# REST Api Structure prevents Database access

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, rest

I'm hosting my files hostinger.in and is implementing REST architecture. When I was implementing the codes without REST, I was getting no error. But now it seems I can't access MySql Database. I narrow down possible errors which comes when I try registering a user and it seems the DB is inaccessible. Here are the codes:

```
  public function sendOtp($mobile, $model, $brand, $device, $fingerprint, $hardware){

    //Checking for User registration
    if (!$this->isUserExists($mobile)) {

       $otp = rand(100000, 999999);

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_register(mobile, registered_mobile_model, registered_mobile_brand, registered_mobile_device, registered_mobile_fingerprint, registered_mobile_hardware, otp) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $mobile, $model, $brand, $device, $fingerprint, $hardware, $otp);

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        //If statment executed successfully
        if ($result) {
            //Returning 0, otp sent
            return 0;
        } else {
            //Returning 1, failed to insert
            return 1;
        }

    } else {
        //user exists, update info and sent otp 


        $otp = rand(100000, 999999);

        //Crating an statement
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE user_register set otp = ?, registered_mobile_model = ?, registered_mobile_brand = ?, registered_mobile_device = ?, registered_mobile_fingerprint = ?, registered_mobile_hardware = ?  WHERE mobile = ?");

        //Binding the parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $otp, $model, $brand, $device, $fingerprint, $hardware, $mobile);

        //Executing the statement
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        //Closing the statement
        $stmt->close();

        //If statement executed successfully
        if ($result) {
            //Returning 0, user insert/update success, otp sent
            return 0;
        } else {
            //Returning 1, failed to insert
            return 1;
        }



    }
}


  private function isUserExists($mobile) {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id from user_register WHERE mobile = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $mobile);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_rows > 0;
}
```

The index.php code to reroute the api calls:

```
     $app->post('/sendotp', function () use ($app) {

//Verifying the required parameters
verifyRequiredParams(array('mobile', 'model', 'brand', 'device', 'fingerprint', 'hardware'));

//Creating a response array
$response = array();

//reading post parameters
$mobile = $app->request->post('mobile');
$model = $app->request->post('model');
$brand = $app->request->post('brand');
$device = $app->request->post('device');
$fingerprint = $app->request->post('fingerprint');
$hardware = $app->request->post('hardware');

//Creating a DbOperation object
$db = new DbOperation();

$res = $db->sendOtp($mobile, $model, $brand, $device, $fingerprint, $hardware);

//If the result returned is 0 means success
if ($res == 0) {
    //Making the response error false
    $response["error"] = false;
    //Adding a success message
    $response["message"] = "OTP Sent";
    //Displaying response
    echoResponse(201, $response);

//If the result returned is 1 means failure
} else if ($res == 1) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registering";
    echoResponse(200, $response);

}
});
```

Comment: Just make sure that your new `DbOperation` does open the connection. Your code looks good (By that I mean it should work). It's not a question of REST or not REST. REST is just the way other system/people call your API, the url organisation and the action. doesn't change the way you connect to your DB. just make sure DbOperation works properly.

Comment: The connection is being opened by DbOperation. I investigated the process and found that the values which comes with the request are null. I didn't used DbOperation and just send back the parameters in response to check and found that they are null. But seems I couldn't answer why? I tried with different chrome extensions to send data but all seems to come as null

Comment: Do you use post method on your browser ?

Comment: Yes I use Post method and content type application/x-www-form-unlencoded.

Comment: In fact I tried with every content type and still getting null values in parameteres

Comment: btw do you use silex? `$app` is the `silex\Application`

Comment: No, I don't use silex. Couldn't figure out why the server is receiving null values.